# grpc event stream / push notifications

Tags: c#, scalability, publish-subscribe, grpc

I'm creating a "Property"-like interface for a domain object.  This means that clients should be notified when a property changes.

Currently it seems that [Grpc wants me](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8718) to create a long lived stream:

```
// .proto file
    rpc Events(Empty) returns (stream Event){}
...

// client code
// for every subscribed event:
var events = _client.GetEvents(empty).ResponseStream;
while (await events.MoveNext()) {
    HandleEvent(events.Current);
}
```

The 'long-lived streaming' call does work for a simple case.  But each of these calls results in a server-side thread.  My solution does not scale to multiple observers.

Can this problem be solved within Grpc?  Or do I have to make sure I only use as little event listeners as possible?  Or use a different protocol for server -> client streams?

Comment: And you are sure (verified) that there is a dedicated server-side thread for each request?

Comment: @Evk: yes.  A blocked one (waiting for the domain to raise an event)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with grpc (though used it once), but why you have to block waiting for domain to raise an event? I mean grpc server seems to support asynchronous execution, so why you have to block synchronously while waiting for event?

Comment: Each long lived call would result in some kind of call context that is waiting somehow for events to arrive.  In this case I did it with a `lock`; but the same amount of 'contexts' is going to be spawned.